# DISTINCT COUNT OF IDS PRESENT IN TWO TIME PERIODS

Tags: sql, date, count, unique

I'd like to understand the distinct count of employees that sold a car in the previous year and in the current one year lookback.  Dates in the example below end 2018-11-18.  I can pull the counts when running with only one  'between and' clause but not meeting both conditions.

```
SELECT COUNT(UNIQUE(EMPLOYEE_ID))
FROM SALES_TABLE_123
WHERE SOLD_ITEM = 'CARS'
AND (SELL_DATE) BETWEEN ('2017-11-19') AND ('2018-11-19')
AND (SELL_DATE) BETWEEN ('2016-11-18') AND ('2017-11-18');
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: 'AND' operator looks for the SELL_DATE for each row to be both in the first interval and the second at the same time; this is impossible because the intervals are not overlapping; would what you are looking for be:
AND ((SELL_DATE) BETWEEN ('2017-11-19') AND ('2018-11-19') OR
          (SELL_DATE) BETWEEN ('2016-11-18') AND ('2017-11-18'));

which could also be written as:
AND SELL_DATE BETWEEN '2016-11-18' AND '2018-11-19';

Comment: @userMT No, as to qualify the record of a sell needs to have occurred in the previous year and the current year.  I can break out and find all IDs that occur in each time period and then do an inner join to see which IDs overlap in two periods, just didn't know if there is a better way to think through this.  Thank you.

Comment: so you mean that a 'sell' should occur for the sell_item in both periods. Your 'breakout and inner join' logic is on the right track for this.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(UNIQUE(LY.EMPLOYEE_ID))
FROM SALES_TABLE_123 LY
     inner join
     SALES_TABLE_123 TY
     on LY.EMPLOYEE_ID=TY.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE LY.SOLD_ITEM = 'CARS'
AND TY.SOLD_ITEM='CARS'
AND TY.SELL_DATE BETWEEN ('2017-11-19') AND ('2018-11-19')
AND LY.SELL_DATE BETWEEN ('2016-11-18') AND ('2017-11-18');
```